# How to use variable in between clause in mysql, php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post

I am creating a search by date feature which should return results from database by searching between two dates. The dates are taken as input in text format.

search.php

```
From: <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker">
To: <input type="text" name="date2" id="datepicker2">
```

The general sql query is of the format

```
mysql> select name,date from events where category='football'and date 
between '2017-09-01' and '2017-09-27' order by name;
```

The php code is as follows:

```
<?php   
$category = $_GET["category"];
$date1= $_GET["date"];
$date2= $_GET["date2"];

$result="SELECT * FROM events WHERE category='$category' AND date BETWEEN  $date1 AND $date2  ";

?>
```

I have tried converting dates using `$d=strtotime($date1);` but that is not working.How to modify the query ?

Comment: First How do you store the date in the database as datetime or varchar or somthing else ??

Comment: what does `var_dump($date1, $date2);` give you?

Comment: I can see an obvious SQL Injection vulnerability... Always escape the input from user or use prepared statement.

Comment: Don't concatenate variables in an SQL statement, certainly not when they come from the request. Danger for SQL Injection!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure in what format you are storing your date in database:

so i would suggest to do the following:

```
<?php       

        $category = $_GET["category"];
        $date1= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET["date"])); 
        $date2= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET["date2"])); 

$result="SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `category`='$category' AND `date` BETWEEN  '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."'  ";

?>
```

Note: I have just changed the date format of both the dates, as you can see in the example provided by you, that the date format in sql query is (Y-m-d).

Second thing: To avoid mysql injection i have added backticks (`) in your query.

So this must help you.

Comment: @SrikaranShenviSursure  You are welcome, can you please also upvote this answer.